# What are the trade offs while moving to functional programming?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming

**Non-Functional way:**
`arr = [1, 2, 3]` becomes `arr = [1, 5, 3]` . Here we change same array.

This is discouraged in functional programming. I know that since computers are becoming faster and faster every day and there is more memory to store, functional programming seems more feasible for better readability and clean code.

**Functional way:**
`arr = [1, 2, 3]` isn't changed `arr2 = [1, 5, 3]`. I see a general trend that we use more memory and time to just change one variable.

Here, we doubled our memory and the time complexity changed from `O(1)` to `O(n)`.

This might be costly for bigger algorithms. Where is this compensated? Or since we can afford for costlier calculations (like when Quantum computing becomes mainstream), do we just trade speed off for readability?

Comment: I wonder why this has close flags for "unclear what is being asked" when it appears I'm perfectly capable of interpreting and answering the question.

Comment: This is a case where larger context becomes pretty important. You typically have less cases where you are specifically changing an element by index when you are programming in a functional style. But, using your particular example if we consider this to be a list, we can share the first elements by saying something like (in Haskell syntax): `let (a:_:c:[]) = arr in let arr2 = a:5:b:[] in ...`. The first and last elements in the new list just point to the same items in memory as the first and last elements in the original list (in the GHC Haskell compiler, anyway). So memory is not doubled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functional data structures don't necessarily take up a lot more space or require more processing time. The important aspect here is that purely functional data structures are immutable, but that doesn't mean you always make a complete copy of something. In fact, the immutability is precisely the key to working efficiently.

I'll provide as an example a simple list. Suppose we have the following list:

[image: list 1]

The head of the list is element `1`. The tail of the list is `(2, 3)`. Suppose this list is entirely immutable.

Now, we want to add an element at the start of that list. Our new list must look like this:

[image: list 2]

You can't change the existing list, it is immutable. So, we have to make a new one, right? However, note how the tail of our new list is `(1, 2 ,3)`. That's identical to the old list. So, you can just re-use that. The new list is simply the element `0` with a pointer to the start of the old list as its tail. Here's the new list with various parts highlighted:

[image: list with highlighted parts]

If our lists were mutable, this would not be safe. If you changed something in the old list (for example, replacing element `2` with a different one) the change would reflect in the new list as well. That's exactly where the danger is in mutability: concurrent access on data structures needs to be synchronized to avoid unpredictable results, and changes can have unintended side-effects. But, because that can't happen with immutable data structures, it's safe to re-use part of another structure in a new one. Sometimes you want changes in one thing to reflect in another; for example, when you remove an entry in the key set of a `Map` in Java, you want the mapping itself to be removed too. But in other situations mutability leads to trouble (the infamous `Calendar` class in Java).

So how can this work, if you can't change the data structure itself? How do you make a new list? Remember that if we're working purely functionally, we move away from the classical data structures with changeable pointers, and instead evaluate functions.

In functional languages, making lists is done with the `cons` function. `cons` makes a "cell" of two elements. If you want to make a list with only one element, the second one is `nil`. So a list with only one `3` element is:

`(cons 3 nil)`

If the above is a function and you ask what its `head` is, you get `3`. Ask for the `tail`, you get `nil`. Now, the tail itself can be a function, like `cons`.

Our first list then is expressed as such:

`(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))`

Ask the `head` of the above function and you get `1`. Ask for the `tail` and you get `(cons 2 (cons 3 nil))`.

If we want to append `0` in the front, you just make a new function that evaluates to `cons` with `0` as head and the above as tail.

`(cons 0 (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))))`

Since the functions we make are immutable, our lists become immutable. Things like adding elements is a matter of making a new function that calls the old one in the right place. Traversing a list in the imperative and object-oriented way is going through pointers to get from one element to another. Traversing a list in the functional way is evaluating functions.

I like to think of data structures as this: **a data structure is basically storing the result of running some algorithm in memory.** It "caches" the result of computation, so we don't have to do the computation every time. Purely functional data structures model the computation itself via functions.

This in fact means that it can be quite memory efficient because a lot of data copying can be avoided. And with an increasing focus on parallelization in processing, immutable data structures can be very useful.

EDIT

Given the additional questions in the comments, I'll add a bit to the above to the best of my abilities.

> What about my example? Is it something like cons(1 fn) and that function can be cons(2 fn2) where fn2 is cons(3 nil) and in some other case cons(5 fn2)?

The `cons` function is best compared to a single-linked list. As you might imagine, if you're given a list composed of `cons` cells, what you're getting is the head and thus random access to some index isn't possible. In your array you can just call `arr[1]` and get the second item (since it's 0-indexed) in the array, in constant time. If you state something like `val list = (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))` you can't just ask the second item without traversing it, because `list` is now actually a function you evaluate. So access requires linear time, and access to the last element will take longer than access to the head element. Also, given that it's equivalent to a single-linked list, traversal can only be in one direction. So the behavior and performance is more like that of a single-linked list than of, say, an arraylist or array.

Purely functional data structures don't necessarily provide better performance for some operations such as indexed access. A "classic" data structure may have O(1) for some operation where a functional one may have O(log n) for the same one. That's a trade-off; functional data structures aren't a silver bullet, just like object-orientation wasn't. You use them where they make sense. If you're always going to traverse a whole list or part of it and want to be capable of safe parallel access, a structure composed of `cons` cells works perfectly fine. In functional programming, you'd often traverse a structure using recursive calls where in imperative programming you'd use a `for` loop.

There are of course many other functional data structures, some of which come much closer to modeling an array that allows random access and updates. But they're typically a lot more complex than the simple example above. There's of course advantages: parallel computation can be trivially easy thanks to immutability; *memoization* allows us to cache the results of function calls based on inputs since a purely functional approach always yields the same result for the same input.

> What are we actually storing underneath? If we need to traverse a list, we need a mechanism to point to next elements right? or If I think a bit, I feel like it is irrelevant question to traverse a list since whenever a list is required it should probably be reconstructed everytime?

We store data structures containing functions. What is a `cons`? A simple structure consisting of two elements: a `head` and `tail`. It's just pointers underneath. In an object-oriented language like Java, you could model it as a class `Cons` that contains two **final** fields `head` and `tail` assigned on construction (immutable) and has corresponding methods to fetch these. This in a LISP variant

`(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))`

would be equivalent to

`new Cons(1, new Cons(2, null))`

in Java.

The big difference in functional languages is that functions are *first-class* types. They can be passed around and assigned to variables just like object references. You can compose functions. I could just as easily do this in a functional language

`val list = (cons 1 (max 2 3))`

and if I ask `list.head` I get 1, if I ask `list.tail` I get `(max 2 3)` and evaluating that just gives me 3. You compose **functions**. Think of it as modeling behavior instead of data. Which brings us to

> Could you elaborate "Purely functional data structures model the computation itself via functions."?

Calling `list.tail` on our above list returns something that can be evaluated and then returns a value. In other words, it returns a function. If I call `list.tail` in that example it returns `(max 2 3)`, clearly a function. Evaluating it yields `3` as that's the highest number of the arguments. In this example

`(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))`

calling `tail` evaluates to a new `cons` (the `(cons 2 nil)` one) which in turn can be used.

Suppose we want a sum of all the elements in our list. In Java, before the introduction of lambdas, if you had an array `int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3}` you'd do something like

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    sum += array[i];
}
```

In a functional language it would be something like (simplified pseudo-code)

```
(define sum (arg)
    (eq arg nil
        (0)
        (+ arg.head (sum arg.tail))
    )
)
```

This uses prefix notation like we've used with our `cons` so far. So `a + b` is written as `(+ a b)`. `define` lets us define a function, with as arguments the name (`sum`), a list of arguments for the function (`(arg)`), and then the actual function body (the rest).

The function body consists of an `eq` function which we'll define as comparing its first two arguments (`arg` and `nil`) and if they're equal it evaluates to its next argument (`(0)` in this case), otherwise to the argument after that (the sum). So think of it as `(eq arg1 arg2 true false)` with true and false whatever you want (a value, a function...).

The recursion bit then comes in the sum `(+ arg.head (sum arg.tail))`. We're stating that we take the addition of the `head` of the argument with a recursive call to the `sum` function itself on the tail. Suppose we do this:

```
val list = (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))
(sum list)
```

Mentally step through what that last line would do to see how it evaluates to the sum of all the elements in `list`.

Note, now, how `sum` is a **function**. In the Java example we had some data structure and then iterated over it, performing access on it, to create our sum. In the functional example the evaluation **is** the computation. A useful aspect of this is that `sum` as a function could be passed around and evaluated only when it's actually needed. That is *lazy evaluation*.

Another example of how data structures and algorithms are actually the same thing in a different form. Take a `set`. A set can contain only one instance of an element, for some definition of equality of elements. For something like integers it's simple; if they are the same value (like `1 == 1`) they're equal. For objects, however, we typically have some equality check (like `equals()` in Java). So how can you know whether a set already contains an element? You go over each element in the set and check if it is equal to the one you're looking for.

A `hash set`, however, computes some hash function for each element and places elements with the same hash in a corresponding bucket. For a good hash function there will rarely be more than one element in a bucket. If you now provide some element and want to check if it's in the set, the actions are:

1. Get the hash of the provided element (typically takes constant time).
2. Find the hash bucket in the set for that hash (again should take constant time).
3. Check if there's an element in that bucket which is equal to the given element.

The requirement is that two equal elements **must** have the same hash.

So now you can check if something is in the set in constant time. The reason being that our data structure itself has stored some computation information: the hashes. If you store each element in a bucket corresponding to its hash, we have put some computation result in the data structure itself. This saves time later if we want to check whether the set contains an element. In that way, **data structures are actually computations frozen in memory**. Instead of doing the entire computation every time, we've done some work up-front and re-use those results.

When you think of data structures and algorithms as being analogous in this way, it becomes clearer how functions can model the same thing.

Make sure to check out the classic book "Structure and Interpetation of Computer Programs" (often abbreviated as SICP). It'll give you a lot more insight. You can read it for free here: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Comment: What about my example? Is it something like `cons(1 fn)` and that function can be `cons(2 fn2)` where fn2 is `cons(3 nil)` and in some other case `cons(5 fn2)`?

Comment: What are we actually storing underneath? If we need to traverse a list, we need a mechanism to point to next elements right? or If I think a bit, I feel like it is irrelevant question to traverse a list since whenever a list is required it should probably be reconstructed everytime?

Comment: Could you elaborate "Purely functional data structures model the computation itself via functions."?

Comment: "data structures are actually computations frozen in memory",    
" In the Java example we had some data structure and then iterated over it, performing access on it, to create our sum. In the functional example the evaluation is the computation." These two sentences explained a lot.

Comment: @TarunMaganti Glad they helped. I'm no functional expert and code in Java for my job, so I know it can be difficult to make the switch to "functional thinking". The SICP book is a really good way of doing that. It helps the understanding that in something like LISP, evaluating the program is actually running it. It also teaches you to think of the program itself as data, since LISPs construct things as list structures, including the program itself.

Comment: I started SICP few months ago. I stopped it due to assignments and exams in college. In my current internship, I'm supposed to learn Javascript and these kinds of questions pop up. I work in Java too. I was a rookie in programming when I started SICP so I didn't fully understand the concepts. ANyway Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a really broad question with a lot of room for opinionated answers, but G_H provides a really nice breakdown of some of the differences

> Could you elaborate "Purely functional data structures model the computation itself via functions."?

This is one of my favourite topics, so I'm happy to share an example in JavaScript because it will allow you to run the code here in the browser and see the answer for yourself

Below you will see a linked list implemented using *functions*. I use a couple Numbers for example data and I use a String so that I can log something to the console for you to see, but other that that, it's just *functions* – no fancy objects, no arrays, no other custom stuff.

```js
const cons = (x,y) => f => f(x,y)

const head = f => f((x,y) => x)

const tail = f => f((x,y) => y)

const nil = () => {}

const isEmpty = x => x === nil

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x))

const reduce = f => y => xs =>
  isEmpty(xs) ? y : reduce (f) (f (y,head(xs))) (tail(xs))
  
const reverse = xs =>
  reduce ((acc,x) => cons(x,acc)) (nil) (xs)
  
const map = f =>
  comp (reverse) (reduce ((acc, x) => (cons(f(x), acc))) (nil))

// this function is required so we can visualise the data
// it effectively converts a linked-list of functions to readable strings
const list2str = xs =>
  isEmpty(xs) ? 'nil' : `(${head(xs)} . ${list2str(tail(xs))})`

// example input data
const xs = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, cons(4, nil))))

// example derived data
const ys = map (x => x * x) (xs)

console.log(list2str(xs))
// (1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . nil))))

console.log(list2str(ys))
// (1 . (4 . (9 . (16 . nil))))
```

Of course this isn't of practical use in real-world JavaScript, but that's beside the point. It's just showing you *how* functions alone could be used to represent complex data structures.

---

Here's another example of implementing rational numbers using nothing but functions and numbers – again, we're only using strings so we can convert the functional structure to a visual representation we can understand in the console - this exact scenario is examine thoroughly in the SICP book that G_H mentions

We even implement our higher-order data `rat` using `cons`. This shows how functional data structures can easily be made up of (composed of) other functional data structures

```
const cons = (x,y) => f => f(x,y)

const head = f => f((x,y) => x)

const tail = f => f((x,y) => y)

const mod = y => x =>
  y > x ? x : mod (y) (x - y)

const gcd = (x,y) =>
  y === 0 ? x : gcd(y, mod (y) (x))

const rat = (n,d) =>
  (g => cons(n/g, d/g)) (gcd(n,d))

const numer = head

const denom = tail

const ratAdd = (x,y) =>
  rat(numer(x) * denom(y) + numer(y) * denom(x),
      denom(x) * denom(y))

const rat2str = r => `${numer(r)}/${denom(r)}`

// example complex data
let x = rat(1,2)
let y = rat(1,4)

console.log(rat2str(x))            // 1/2
console.log(rat2str(y))            // 1/4
console.log(rat2str(ratAdd(x,y)))  // 3/4
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful in trans-visualising (if that word exists) how functional way works through the lens of object/imperative languages.

Comment: @TarunMaganti I might suggest you also introduce yourself to [the lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) – at their core, all functional languages (even a remarkable amount of imperative, procedural, or even object-oriented languages too) have their roots in the lambda calculus. It all comes down to functions...

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that. But if I'm not wrong both representation through functions (Lambda Calculus) and through states (Turing machines) are Turing complete. So, everything might also boil down to stateful representation too :P

Comment: @TarunMaganti I once heard someone state something interesting. It was along the lines of "there is no software, just hardware that moves from one state to the other". Too bad I don't remember where, I think it was actually on an SE site.

Comment: @Tarun, if I'm not mistaken, it's Turing's machine that is at the roots of hardware and Church's lambda calculus that is at the roots of programming language theory. But yes, the two are equivalent.